# Autoplay unmute YouTube video in iFrame or some alternative

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net-mvc, iframe

For several days I am trying to autoplay unmuted video based on embed from youtube.

In the repository I am generating two types of string which are passed to view:

`finalUrl = String.Format("https://www.youtube.com/embed/videoseries?list=" + videoList + "&version=3&enablejsapi=1&iv_load_policy=3&loop=1&autoplay=1&mute=1&vq=hd1080");`

`finalUrl = String.Format("https://www.youtube.com/embed/" + videoId + "?version=3&enablejsapi=1&iv_load_policy=3&loop=1&autoplay=1&mute=1&vq=hd1080&playlist=" + videoId);`

When I try to do `&autoplay=1&mute=0`  or  `&autoplay=1` it is unmuted but video doesn't start.

In .cshtml I am using iFrame to render video:

```
           <div class="responsive-video">
               <iframe id="youtube-video" class="video center-block"
                       src="@Model.youTubeVideoData.Description"
                       frameborder="0" allow="autoplay"></iframe>
           </div>
       </div>
```

I also tried to use

```
            player.unMute();
            player.playVideo();
```

but without any success.

Is it possible to create autoplay unmuted in 2020? In a different way? Maybe I should use some external library to do that? Someone had similar problem to mine?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?